# Class Pointer Losing Members?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, dereference

I have a binary tree, that I am searching:

```
TreeNode<Vessel*>* node = this->tree_->search("PotatoFace");
string mystring = node->print();
```

when I run it, node contains the correct data, but when I go to print that data as soon as I enter:

```
string TreeNode<T>::print()
{
return data_->toString();
}
```

'this' (which should be the 'node' and has the same memory address as 'node') has all of its data members including the Vessel* set to null.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Full Tree Node:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TreeNode
{
private:
TreeNode<T>* greaterNode_;
TreeNode<T>* lessNode_;
TreeNode<T>* parentNode_;
TreeNode<T>* getLowest_();
T data_;


public:
TreeNode();
TreeNode(T data);
void add(T data);
bool operator==(const string &rhs);
TreeNode* search(T data);
void seqSearch(string data, TreeNode<T>* node);
void del(TreeNode<T>* root);
void toFile(ofstream& BSTFile);
TreeNode* compare(int sig[4]);
TreeNode* getRoot();
TreeNode* forward(TreeNode<T>* node);

string print();
};


template <class T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(T data)
{
data_ = data;
greaterNode_ = lessNode_ = parentNode_= NULL;

}
template <class T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode()
{
}

template <class T>
void TreeNode<T>::seqSearch(string data, TreeNode<T>* node )
{
if(*data_ == data)
{
    *node = this->data_;
}
if(this->lessNode_)
{
    this->lessNode_->seqSearch(data, node);
}   
if(this->greaterNode_)
{
    this->greaterNode_->seqSearch(data, node);
}   
}

template <class T>
string TreeNode<T>::print()
{
return data_->toString();
}
```

Still not entirely sure how to explain why it wasn't working, but it was a scope issue, outside the binary tree class tree nodes lost data. Taken out all tree functions that returned nodes and everything works now.

Comment: Post the definitions. Also, you do realize that `TreeNode<Vessel*>* node = new TreeNode<Vessel*>();` is useless, since you reassign `node` in the next line, and also results in a memory leak?

Comment: corrected that, it was set like this before but whilst trying to fix it, I changed it.

Comment: What is toString? Also, why are you keeping pointers and not objects in your class?

Comment: toString() returns a string containing all the members of the data_ class, which is a pointer because there are 3 levels of inheritance in my tree, so it can store 6 different types of vessel.

Comment: Is TreeNode<Vessel*>* hello = this->tree_->search("PotatoFace");
string mystring = node->print(); being executed within the scope of the class or within a separate scope (e.g. a main function)?

Comment: separate scope. 

At I'm finding this for all my functions, anything that returns a TreeNode*, the TreeNode* has it's data deleted when it's dereferenced. Really confused.

Comment: Run your program under valgrind.  It is a tool to find memory access errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not entirely sure how to explain why it wasn't working, but it was a scope issue, outside the binary tree class tree nodes lost data.

It was rectified by ensuring that the Binary Tree class doesn't return anything of type TreeNode*, and running whatever other function I wanted once I had the value of the node was done inside the binary tree class. This works now. 
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you wanted to write:

```
string mystring = node->print();
```

not

```
string mystring = hello->print();
```

If yes, it seems like 'this' of

```
string mystring = node->print();
```

is null (node is null). This may have several reasons:

- node never gets initialized
- node should be set by search("something") but search returns null

It would be really helpful if you paste more code.